# How to make OneToOne relationship using join on secondary key?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client extends Model {

    @Id
    public int id;

    public String name;

    @OneToOne
    public Contact contact;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
public class Contact extends Model {

    @Id
    public int id;

    @OneToOne
    @Column(name = "client_name")
    public String clientName;
}
```

Now I want to set OneToOne relationship but join using client_name column (`on clients.name=contacts.client_name`). How to do that?

I know that it is better to join using primary key but database structure is fixed and I can't change it.

Comment: I think you should use, not sure if Ebean supports it: @JoinColumn(name = "client_name") in Context.class (optional) and @OneToOne(mappedBy="client_name") (mandatory).

Comment: @adis now it complains that `PersistenceException: Error on models.Client.contact. mappedBy property [models.Contact.clientName]is not a OneToOne?` probably because `clientName` is a String.

Comment: @adis but if I make it `Client` then it will say `Unknown column 't1.client_name_id'`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@OneToOne
@Column(name = "client_name")
@JoinColumn(name = "client_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
public Client client;
```